# Traversing EF Model and getting the property names

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to implement a function that traverses an EF Models and gets the names of all relevant properties (columns). Assume that there are the following classes in the EF:

```
public class A {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public int TotalNumber {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual B classB {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<D> classesD {get; set;} = new List<D>();
}

public class B {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public datetime Timestamp {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public virtual C Sender {get; set;}
    public virtual C Receiver {get; set;}
}

public class C {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class D {
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string ErrorMsg {get; set;}
    public datetime Timestamp {get; set;}
}
```

For class A, I should be able to get the following tuples: `(TotalNumber, int), (Name, string), (classB.Timestamp, datetime), (classB.Description, string), (classB.Sender.Name. string), (classB.Receiver.Name, string)`. The class D can be ignored as it is a collection and I don't want to do that for collections.

At the first step, I implemented a function, which does this for a parent (main) class:

```
public virtual List<Tuple<string, string>> GetSqlColumnNames(string sqlTableName, bool addPrefix)
{
    var columnNames = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
    var ignoredTypes = new List<string> { "uniqueidentifier"};
    var ignoredNames = new List<string> { "CreatedBy", "CreatedOn", "ModifiedBy", "ModifiedOn", "Version", "ValidFrom", "ValidTo"};

    foreach (var entityType in DBContext.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        if (entityType.GetTableName()==sqlTableName)
        {
            foreach (var entityProperty in entityType.GetProperties())
            {
                if (!ignoredTypes.Contains(entityProperty.GetColumnType()) && !ignoredNames.Contains(entityProperty.GetColumnName()))
                {
                    columnNames.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(
                        addPrefix
                            ? sqlTableName + "." + entityProperty.GetColumnName()
                            : entityProperty.GetColumnName(), entityProperty.GetColumnType()));
                }
            }
            return columnNames;
        }
    }
    return columnNames;
}
```

The function above works as expected. However, I am not sure how to extend this in a way that it works also with subojects (subclasses). I tried to go via foreign keys, but no luck:

```
foreach (var foreignKey in entityType.GetForeignKeys())
{
    var tableName = _transactionDatabaseContext.Model.FindEntityType(foreignKey.GetType()).GetTableName(); // incorrect as foreignKey.GetType() returns something else
    //columnNames.AddRange(GetSqlColumnNames(tableName, true));
}
```

Can anyone suggest, how could I possibly resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```cs
> // incorrect as foreignKey.GetType() returns something else
> ```

Correct. Instead of

```
Model.FindEntityType(foreignKey.GetType())
```

use [`PrincipalEntityType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.iforeignkey.principalentitytype?view=efcore-5.0) property

```cs
foreach (var foreignKey in entityType.GetForeignKeys())
{
    var tableName = foreignKey.PrincipalEntityType.GetTableName();
    //columnNames.AddRange(GetSqlColumnNames(tableName, true));
}
```

Note that you have to check for self references and handle them specially (basically process each unique FK only once), otherwise you will enter infinite loop, and at the end - stack overflow exception.